# firebase.auth().setPersistence error of 'Persistence' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am using Firebase `auth` to handle authentication of users in a form but am getting this error

> error of 'Persistence' of undefined

when adding `firebase.auth().setPersistence`.

```
onSubmit = event => {
  const { firebase } = this.props;
  const { email, password, remember } = this.state;
  firebase
    .doSignInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password, remember)
    .then(authUser => {
      firebase.doEmailUpdateUser(authUser);
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.setState({ error: null });
      navigate(ROUTES.INDEX);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.setState({
        error,
        errorOpen: true
      });
    });

  event.preventDefault();
};
```

Whereas `firebase.doSignInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password, remember)` is

```
doSignInWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password, remember) => {
  this.auth
    .setPersistence(
      `${
        remember
          ? this.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL
          : this.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION
      }`
    )
    .then(() => this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password));
};
```

for reference `this.auth = app.auth();`

Have I missed something here? What have I done wrong?

Comment: you don't have to pass around firebase and auth references.
Can you try to change your firebase and auth properties with directly importing them and try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to get `Auth.Persistence` from the wrong object. You say `this.auth = app.auth()`, so i assume then that `app` was imported from firebase something like `import app from 'firebase'`. If that's incorrect, please show me how you're importing.

If my assumptions were correct, then you'll need to access the properties like `app.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL`. Your current version is more like `app.auth().Auth.Persistence.LOCAL`

Comment: Thank you @Nicholas Tower. You were spot on... for me the problem happened to be that `app` was not being passed correctly to the `Auth.Persistence` function. Thanks for your help.